# Can't see exported function in dumpbin

Tags: c++, linker, dumpbin

```
              my.dll
                |
     _______________________
    |           |           |
lib1.lib  lib2.lib  ...  libn.lib
```

In lib1.lib I export a function called foo(). When I call dumpbin /exports my.dll I can't see the function. What should I do? I do that in Visual Studio 2017 C++.

Comment: You should not see anything from your static libraries. Only the functions and variables you export from your dll will be visible.

Comment: I found a solution: setting "Use Library Dependency Inputs" to true for lib1.lib

Comment: You can answer you own question.